# Why does Safari ignore transition events like transitionend?

Tags: javascript, safari, mobile-safari

I've added a simple `ontransitionend` listener. The code works in Firefox and Chrome, but doesn't in Safari (desktop + iOS). I've tried syntax variations and used AlpineJS ([Codepen](https://codepen.io/kslstn/pen/KKZQxRM)) to do the same. But the problem appears to be with Safari not reacting at all to transition events. What could be happening here?

```js
const el = document.getElementById('hasTransition');
el.ontransitionend = () => {
  document.getElementById('message').classList.remove('hidden');
};
```

```css
#hasTransition{
  transition: all linear 200ms;
}
.hidden{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="el.classList.remove('hidden')">
  Click to trigger a transition
</button>
<p id="message" class="hidden">We've detected a transition.</p>
<p id="hasTransition" class="hidden">✨ I'm visible ✨</p>
```

Comment: Your Stack Snippet works just fine for me on iOS Safari (v15.3.1). It initially just shows the button, then clicking it I see the *I'm visible* followed very quickly by *"We've detected a transition"* just like I do on non-Safari desktop.

Comment: Thanks for checking! Oddly, today it works on my Safari's too!

Comment: Actually, the AlpineJS version I linked to still doesn't work. I suspect it's an AlpineJS bug. After all, the issue isn't with JS's ontransitionend and the behavior shouldn't be inconsistent between browsers.